# Integral involving the von Mises-Fisher distribution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I'm going quickly through the VonMises-Fisher distribution $M$ on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ and its properties. Its probability density function is:

$$f(x; \kappa,\mu)= c(\kappa)\exp(\kappa x^T\mu)$$

where $\kappa \times \mu \in[0,\infty)\times \mathbb S^{d-1}$ are fixed parameters and $c(\kappa)$ is a normalizing constant so the whole thing will integrate $1$. Specifically,

$$c(\kappa)=\left(\frac\kappa2\right)^{d/2-1}\frac1{\Gamma(d/2)I_{d/2-1}(\kappa)}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and $I_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order $\nu$ is
$$I_\nu(\kappa) = \frac{(\kappa/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu +\frac12)\Gamma(\frac12)}\int_{-1}^1e^{\kappa t}(1-t^2)^{\nu -\frac12}dt.$$

The paper I'm reading mentions the following equality without further explanation

> $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}_{\geq\frac1r}}f_\kappa(\xi) \, d\xi = c(\kappa) \frac{s_{d-2}}{s_{d-1}} \int_0^{\arccos(-\log(rc(\kappa))/\kappa)} e^{\kappa\cos\theta} \sin^{d-2} \theta \, d\theta$$
>   where $s_{d-1}=\displaystyle \frac{2\pi^{\frac d2}}{\Gamma(\frac d2)}$ and 
>   $$\mathbb S_{\geq\frac1r}^{d-1} =\{x\in\mathbb S^{d-1}:f(x;\kappa,\mu)\geq r\}$$ for a fixed $r>0$

I'm a bit rusty on multivariable integration. I thought on spherical coordinates, but I'm not sure how does it work when I'm working on $d-1$ dimensions.

How can I get the highlighted equality?

Comment: I am probably not of much help, but I do know that Kappa is the concentration parameter, which is the inverse of the standard deviation an mu is the origin (mean equivalent) which the kappa is centered around.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the paper you found this equation in? Thank you.